# Jstree How to change “New node” Label when creating a new node?

Tags: jstree

I'm using contextmenu plugin when create new node and then have my own function to do creating the new node using ajax post back.

```
$("#tree").jstree({
            //....

            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "crrm", "contextmenu", "dnd", "ui", "cookies"]
})
//...
.bind("create.jstree", function (e, data) {
             //...
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    //...
                    });
});
```

I would like to change the default label of "New node" to "New folder" when click on "create".
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you change the context menu options

```
$("#tree").jstree({
"plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"],
"contextmenu": {
    "items": function ($node) {
        return {
            "Create": {
                "label": "New Folder",
                "action": function (obj) {
                    this.create(obj);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
});
```

Updated

You can find this part in jquery.jstree.js file

```
if(!js.data) { js.data = this._get_string("new_node"); }
```

change this part to

```
if(!js.data) { js.data = this._get_string("new folder"); }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will change the 'create' to 'New Folder' in contextmenu. But I mean when you select create from contextmenu it creates a node and labels it 'new node' by default. What I want to do is changing this label from 'new node' to 'New Folder' or anything else. Any other solution?

Comment: I am not sure of the optimal soultion, but this seems to work. just search for new node in jquery.jstree.js and change the name from new_node to New Folder.

Comment: Going off of another SO article and this you can load it dynamically through the context menu like this (and I apologize for the unformatted code): `"action": function (data) {
                  var inst = $.jstree.reference(data.reference),
                  obj = inst.get_node(data.reference);
                  inst.create_node(obj, {}, "last", function (new_node) {
                  new_node.data = {type: "file"};
                  new_node.text = "Unamed Document";
                  setTimeout(function () { inst.edit(new_node); },0);
              });`

Answer (score 13):

Here's how to change strings in jsTree v.3. Note this is different from earlier versions because the key is the text you want to change (`'New node'` instead of `new_node`):

```
$("#content_tree").jstree({
    core: {
        strings : {
            'New node': 'Your Text'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation, you just have to define the string parameter in the core settings.

For example:

```
        $("#content_tree").jstree({
            core: {
                animation: 100,
                strings : { loading : "Loading ...", new_node : "New folder" }
            },
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data"]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the line after initialize the `create_node` event

```
data.node.text = 'My Custom Name';
```

example:

```
$('#selector').jstree( ... ).on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

   data.node.text = 'My Custom Name';

   ...

});
```

add

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I changed the new node to new folder in jquery.jstree.js file in the defaults and it worked. Thank you again.

```
$.jstree.plugin("core", {
        __init : function () {
            this.data.core.locked = false;
            this.data.core.to_open = this.get_settings().core.initially_open;
            this.data.core.to_load = this.get_settings().core.initially_load;
        },
        defaults : { 
            html_titles : false,
            animation   : 500,
            initially_open : [],
            initially_load : [],
            open_parents : true,
            notify_plugins : true,
            rtl         : false,
            load_open   : false,
            strings     : {
                loading     : "Loading ...",
                new_node    : "New folder",
                multiple_selection : "Multiple selection"
            }
        },
```